# invalidateOptionsMenu() not working

Tags: android, notifications, onesignal

i want to update notification count badge on my android apps every time new notification receive from one signal notification class. the flow is, anytime new notification receive, i will save the count to sharedpreference. its already done and everytime notification receive, the count badge will be updated, problem is to update the icon in toolbar is using invalidate option menu.
So i make this method in my MainActivity class

```
public void updateNotif(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> notif = notif_count.getCount();
    count = notif.get(NotifCountSession.KEY_COUNT);
    Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "COUNT : "+count);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

and then i call it inside OneSignal notification class like below

```
public class Notification implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {

private NotifCountSession session;

private Application app;
private int count;
public Notification(Application app){
    this.app = app;
}

@Override
public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {

    init();
    count++;
    session.saveCount(count);
//this code works
    Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "COUNT NOTIF : "+count);
//but this one not
    new MainActivity().updateNotif();
}

private void init(){
    session = new NotifCountSession(app);
    HashMap<String, Integer> notif = session.getCount();
    count = notif.get(session.KEY_COUNT);
}
}
```

below is my notification count badge [image]

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: This line `new MainActivity().updateNotif()` Is a Disaster . Never ever create an Activity's instance . Its a component which instantiated by system itself .

Comment: so how to make it work ?

Comment: I suggest you should read about `Activity` first . Its the backbone of  android . To make it work you can broadcast a message or call a static method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these step to update from notification.

1) Add in your MainActivity

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMyBroadcastReceiver;
```

Then ,

2) In onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateNotif();
        }
    };
    try {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("your_action"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

// and your other code

3) Then unregister in onPause

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

4) Finally in your `notificationReceived` method

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your_action");  
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Welcome bro. Best of luck.